# Rails 6.1 ArgumentError: Rendering layouts from an absolute path is not supported

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have upgraded rails to 6.1 and encountered the issue in

**`CreatePdf.new(content: render_to_string('/pdfs/books/show')).call`**

ArgumentError: Rendering layouts from an absolute path is not supported.

What should be the correct way to pass the path in render_to_string?

Comment: Have you tried, 'pdfs/books/show' ?

Comment: Worth a try: Rails.root.join('app', 'views', 'pdfs', 'books', 'show.html.haml')